# Ionic-Angular can't get list to scroll properly

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I've been trying to programmatically scroll a list (accordion) in an Ionic-Angular app and I’ve been having no success at all.

I reproduced it in this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-ionic-scroll-problem?file=src/app/home/home.page.ts

When you click on an item, it expands and I want it to align to the top of the screen (with the title visible).  In this example, I am using scrollIntoView() to get it to the top but it disappears behind the toolbar.

I've tried many things to get it to align properly (including setting a "scroll-margin-top" as suggested on many posts) but this hasn't worked for me.

Also, I can't seem to be able to use the scrollBy() or scrollTo() method... they do nothing at all.

Can anybody help me figure this out and get this precise example to work?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the property `[fullscreen]="true"` of the `<ion-content>` tag.

The property `fullscreen` of ion-content, according to the ionic documentation...

> If true, the content will scroll behind the headers and footers. This effect can easily be seen by setting the toolbar to transparent.

In ionic when you use the option fullscreen as in `<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">` it adds the following style to the ion-content tag:

```
--offset-top: 56px;
```

The goal of the `[fullscreen]="true"` is to create the effect of the content scrolling behind the header.

As a side effect, part of the `<ion-content>` is hidden behind the `<ion-header>`.

**Fullscreen property and scrollIntoView()**

According to w3schools...

> The scrollIntoView() method scrolls the specified element into the visible area of the browser window.

So, in your code, when you call scrollIntoView() of a group it is working exactly as expected. The screen is scrolled until the top o the group is into the visible area of the browser. The problem is that the `<ion-header>` is covering part of the top of this visible area.

**Solution:**

If you remove the `[fullscreen]="true"` of the `<ion-content>`tag the scroll will work as you expect.

But you will loose the effect created by the fullscreen property (content scrolling behing the header).

**References**

Fullscreen property of ion-content tag:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content

ScrollIntoView:
https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

Comment: Well, wasn't that easy? I could have sworn that I had tried that... apparently not. Thanks a lot!  Do you, by any chance, know why I scrollTo() and scrollBy() have no apparent effect?

Comment: Usually commands like window.scrollTo() etc they dont work because the window itself has no scroll. The scroll is in the ion-content. So what I do is adding `@ViewChild(IonContent) ionContent: IonContent;` to the page and then invoking commands like `this.ionContent.scrollByPoint(0,300);`